# Uninstall OpenShot

Tags: apt, openshot

Ubuntu says that OpenShot is not installed.  It clearly is, as you can see in this screenshot.  I've tried a number of variants, including apt remove openshot*, OpenShot, and so on.  All the info I can find says this should have worked.  I'd like to remove it because it is unstable on my system.

Commands such as sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove openshot return "openshot is not installed"  As you can see it is installed and running.  [image]

[EDIT]  Here is the output of apt-cache:

```
lawrence@DianneFosseyT5500:~$ apt-cache search openshot*
gpsshogi - Shogi playing program based on OpenShogiLib
gpsshogi-data - data files for gpsshogi
gpsshogi-dbg - Shogi playing program based on OpenShogiLib
libosl-dev - library for Shogi playing programs
libosl-doc - library for Shogi playing programs
libosl1v5 - library for Shogi playing programs
libosl1v5-dbg - library for Shogi playing programs
openshot-doc - Help manual for OpenShot Video Editor
libopenshot-audio5 - Audio library used by OpenShot
libopenshot-audio-dev - Development files for libopenshot-audio
libopenshot12 - Library for creating and editing videos
libopenshot-dev - Development files for libopenshot
python-libopenshot - Python bindings for libopenshot
openshot-qt - Create and edit videos and movies.
openshot - Create and edit videos and movies.
lawrence@DianneFosseyT5500:~$
```

[Edit] sudo apt list --installed does not produce any output that lists anything like openshot.

Attempting to install openshot again results in this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

openshot : Depends: melt but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python-mlt but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Did you installed via a snap? What does snap put out (use the command `snap list` )?

Comment: I don't see it listed in snaps:   ~$ snap list 
Name              Version  Rev   Tracking  Developer  Notes
arduino-mhall119  1.6.10   3     stable    mhall119   -
core              16-2.33  4830  stable    canonical  core
libreoffice       6.0.4.2  65    stable    canonical  -

Comment: I did something with flatpack the other day, but I don't think it was a flatpack either, if that is relevant.  Flatpack is no longer on my system.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt remove openshot-qt` ?

Comment: Just tried that again.  Still says it is not installed.  Also dpkg -l | grep openshot* produces no output.

Comment: Otherwise list installed apt using the following command: `apt list --installed openshot*`

Comment: Also produces no output.  Seems like I have something broken here pretty bad, no?

Comment: try `apt list --installed | grep openshot` , and type `which openshot` to see where the program is run from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79606/discussion-between-invention1-and-abu-bua).

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that something is seriously broken on my system.  I have some broken dependencies in ffmpeg, and my efforts at fixing that have probably only made things worse.  "Yes I've tried that" is the answer to most of the answers people will helpfully give here.  I'm getting ready to upgrade to 18.04.1 LTS, and am seriously considering a fresh install, then reinstall all the programs I am using.  I'll leave this question open for a while longer, but basically APT doesn't know anything about openshot, something is really broken.

Comment: Voting to close as “can't be reproduced” as [OP has reinstalled their system](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051301/250300).

Answer (score 4):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove openshot-qt
```

I think it's just a syntax problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

These symptoms result from some seriously broken dependencies.  Basically, apt doesn't know about the program in question on this broken system. Any fix using apt just isn't gonna get you anywhere.   The big-hammer fix will be to do a fresh install of 18.04 LTS, which happily just dropped, instead of doing a release upgrade.  Fortunately I've set my system up so this will be pretty easy with little risk of losing the files, which are also backed up several ways.  Thanks for your help folks.